# Mocking formbuilder with phpunit in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

So trying to write unit tests against my Symfony controller, and hit this snag.

My controller method returns a form, I'd like to check the values in that form to make sure it's as expected.

1. I can't find any way to correctly mock the formbuilder,
2. I don't know how I'll be able to verify the values passed to it even if i could mock it

Here's what I've got (distilled)

```
$formBuilder = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\FormBuilderInterface',Array('add'));

$formFactory = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface');

$formFactory
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('createBuilder')
        ->will($this->returnValue($formBuilder));
```

And Setting so that when Symfony asks for the  'form.factory' from the context, it receives my $formBuilder.

Then in my controller, a simple form

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('CountryCode', 'text')
        ->add('State', 'text')
        ->add('Locality', 'text')
        ->add('OrganizationName', 'text')
        ->add('OrganizationalUnitName', 'text')
        ->add('CommonName', 'text')
        ->add('EmailAddress', 'text')
        ->add('company', 'text')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

I have verified that the CreateFormBuilder call to the base controller is in fact returning the mocked form builder interface, but the add method is not available, and it all just blows up with

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object
```

which implies that my formbuilder is not doing the right thing...

So I've seen a lot of discussion about this, but no answers , other than 'don't unit test your controller methods' , which isn't really a good answer. The Symfony Documentation is about unit testing their FormBuilder function, which is odd... http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be getting the error due to chaining the formBuilders 'add' method. Your mocked formBuilder add method will need to return itself.

```
$formBuilder->expects($this->any())
         ->method('add')
         ->will($this->returnSelf());
```

Comment: that's the one. thanks. any thought as to how we'd do this in a way that lets us check the values that were set in the form by the controller?